# PostgreSQL Warm Standby performance really slow

Tags: postgresql

We have a master database with a warm standby (PostgreSQL 10.9, Windows, 64-bit). Both databases have the same configuration settings except for the effective_cache_size (master is 32GB and standby is 16GB, based on available RAM). I tried a simple test query on both servers:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Prescription" rx
WHERE "PharmacyId" = '1ec0cec5-1cbc-412f-9765-ac0f010de111' AND "RxNumber" = '4181800'
LIMIT 500;
```

I was surprised by the difference in execution times (note that the query plans are the same):

| PROD (Master): |  |
| --- | --- |
| Processor | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v4 @ 2.30GHz, 2295 Mhz, 16 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s) |
| Memory | 56.0 GB |
| Query Plan | https://explain.depesz.com/s/Qcdy |
| Query Time | 2 minutes 25 seconds |

| REPORT (Standby): |  |
| --- | --- |
| Processor | Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2673 v3 @ 2.40GHz, 2397 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 8 Logical Processor(s) |
| Memory | 28.0 GB |
| Query Plan | https://explain.depesz.com/s/4MiN |
| Query Time | 17 minutes 2 seconds |

Table information:

```
CREATE TABLE public."Prescription"
(
    "Id" uuid NOT NULL,
    "RecordVersion" integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    "RecordCreatedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "RecordModifiedAt" timestamp without time zone,
    "AcquisitionCost" numeric(19,4),
    "DateCancelled" timestamp without time zone,
    "DateDispensed" timestamp without time zone,
    "DateSold" timestamp without time zone,
    "GroupNumber" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Insurer" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "NDC" character varying(11) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "PatientPaid" numeric(19,4),
    "PCN" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ProductName" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "Quantity" numeric(19,4),
    "RxNumber" character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "ThirdPartyPaid" numeric(19,4),
    "TotalClaimPrice" numeric(19,4),
    "PharmacyId" uuid,
    CONSTRAINT "Prescription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("Id"),
    CONSTRAINT "Prescription_PharmacyId_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("PharmacyId")
        REFERENCES public."Pharmacy" ("Id") MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        DEFERRABLE
);

CREATE INDEX "INDEX_Prescription_PharmacyIde60cffc4508643c09b6263ec4bdf0987"
    ON public."Prescription" USING btree
    ("PharmacyId")
    WITH (FILLFACTOR=50)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

For such a simple query, I'm at a loss to explain the discrepancy between the query times. The query plans are identical. The data is identical. I would not think that PROD's extra processors and RAM would really matter in such a simple case. I tried doing a VACUUM, ANALYZE, and REINDEX on the warm standby but that fails because the database is in perpetual "recovery" mode. I realize that adding an index containing `RxNumber` would help both, but that is not an option. The question is, why is my warm standby database so much slower than the master database? How can I even investigate why?

Comment: [`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) ...`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) Probably here you will see the difference

Comment: PS: In any case 2 minutes for query ... Something wrong with DB desigion. My personal rule: not more then 1 ms per row.

Comment: @Abelisto I have already performed EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) on both machines. See links above labeled "Query Plan". Both machines ran the same query plan.

Comment: What happens if you run the query repeatedly on the standby?  Does it remain slow, or is repeat execution faster?

Comment: "Recheck Cond" Increase [`work_mem`](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/work_mem/) parameter.

Comment: You didn't describe the IO subsystems.  Are they the same between the two servers?

Comment: "Buffers: shared hit=34 read=2,022,635" 2M rows was readed from the disk. Increase [shared_buffers](https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/shared_buffers/)

Comment: @Abelisto  recheck will always be listed as part of the plan, but since no rows were removed by recheck and no blocks were listed as lossy, rechecking is not actually happening.

Comment: @jjanes Recheck happens when there is no memory to hold the result of the operation.

Comment: @Abelisto But "Recheck Cond" only means that it stands ready to do rechecks, not that it has actually done any of them.  Lack of memory is one reason for it to do rechecks, but that would show up as lossy blocks in the 'Heap Blocks' line.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "hot" standby.  A "warm" standby is constantly replaying WAL records, but does not allow anyone to connect in order to do (read-only) queries against it.

It looks like the query on the standby is setting a massive number of hint bits on table rows which are no longer visible.  Or at least, I don't know what else could explain the

```
dirtied=565,583
```

on the bitmap heap scan.  But once set, they shouldn't need to be set again, so what happens if you repeat the same query back to back?  The first execution should clear a path for the second one to be much faster.

It also looks like this table is woefully under-vacuumed.  Now it can't be undervacuumed just on the standby of course, because as you note vacuuming can only occur on the master.
But being under-vacuumed can have a worse penalty on the standby than it does on the master.